# Are we actually forbidden from linking to external tools such as codepen/jsfiddle?

Tags: discussion, jsfiddle, external-links

On one of my answers yesterday I had the following comment.

[image: stackoverflow_comment]

Since stackexchange implemented the code snippet feature, are we forbidden from linking to external tools such as codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: There is someone I find very annoying who regularly comments on posts requesting the code be put up as a pen/fiddle. It's especially annoying when the answer is so obvious that a fiddle would make no difference at all.

Answer (score 6):

You can still use external sites like codepen and jsfiddle. You don't have to use the Stack Snippets.

However, you must include the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself, otherwise your question could be closed as not providing enough information to solve the issue. Just providing a link to your code is not enough.

If someone edits your question to also include a Stack Snippet, I'd say that is OK, since some answerers may prefer stack snippets instead of external tools. It seems that commenter is a user who prefers to use the Stack Snippets.

In closing, it's up to you which one you want to use or if you don't want to use any. All we really need is the MCVE, the rest is the questioner's preference. Just keep in mind that some answerers may prefer one over the other.

Comment: To emphasize this a bit more, policy on fiddles hasn't changed at all since Snippets were introduced: they have always been permitted, but actual code within the actual question has always been required. "Link-only" questions are as bad as link-only answers.

Comment: What I hate is when a question includes some code and then somebody edits it to turn the code into a snippet that doesn't work.